# VSCode: How to document promise that resolves with complex object?

Tags: documentation, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I have a function `f` that returns a `Promise`. The returned `Promise` either `resolve({name: String, data: Object})` or `reject(Error)`.

I've tried the following syntax(as mentioned in [an issue in JSDoc](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/1197)) in VSCode, but it doesn't work:

```
/**
 * @promise fPromise
 * @reject {Error}
 * @fulfill {Object} project
 * @fulfill {Object} project.data
 * @fulfill {String} project.name
 * @returns fPromise
*/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your best bet is to wrap your `fulfill` response into a custom object:

```
/**
 * @promise fPromise
 * @reject {Error}
 * @fulfill {Project}
 * @returns {Promise.<Project>}
*/
function renderResults(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(new Project())
    })
}

renderResults()

function Project() {
    this.data = "data";
    this.name = "project phoenix"
    this.location = {
        city: 'seattle',
        state: 'wa'
    }
}
```

This will show in VS Code like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To be as clear as possible, why not put the nature of the object on a single line for the description? Its just supposed to be a description of that fulfill.

```
/**
 * @promise fPromise
 * @fulfill {Object} A project object with the format {name: String, data: Object}
 * @reject {Error}
 * @returns fPromise
*/
```

Or, if you want to handle dynamically generated object keys, similar to the [Google Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml#JsTypes):

```
/**
 * @promise fPromise
 * @fulfill {Object.<String, Object>} 
 * @reject {Error}
 * @returns fPromise
*/
```

That allows anyone reading your comment to understand what the returned object looks like, what the keys are, and what type of value should be in each key.

*Unless*, you're trying to say that it can return any of the three possibilities. Then I think your original format is a little bit more descriptive of the possible results of the Promise being fulfilled.

Comment: In my case, the result of fulfilled promise may contain 10+ static keys, so it is inconvenient to document them in a single line.